# Unable to upgrade from 9.x to 10.x

Tags: teamcity, upgrade, teamcity-9.0

I am a teamcity developer and our organisation currently uses Team-city 9.0.3 Free version. Now we maxed out Builds. So we are planning to take an enterprise edition.

But before that we need to upgrade the teamcity to latest version 10.x. while i am doing the upgrade it throws the following error.

[Please click the link to see the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuhJO.png)

The steps i did for the upgrade are
-- Take a back up of entire Teamcity which will be in  /root/.BuildServer/backup
-- Stop the Teamcity server and delete the whole teamcity directory
-- copy the backup .Zip file into import section.
-- download the latest teamcity and do the necessary configurations and start the teamcity server.
-- go to Administration/Import and start importing the file  from /root/.BuildServer/import

While importing i am getting the above error as version is not supported.

Please help me on this so that i have to upgrade the Teamcity and go for enterprise edition

Thankyou in advance..

Comment: It says you're running TeamCity 9, did you start the right version of the software?

Comment: No, Currently we are on 9.x and i took a backup of 9.x and trying to import into 10.x. Basically my aim is to upgrade teamcity from 9.x to 10.x

Comment: You can't do that, you must install TeamCity 10 on top of TeamCity 9 and let it upgrade in-place. So yes, make backups, but you cannot import TC9 backup into TC10.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to import a backup created with TeamCity 9 into TeamCity 10, that isn't supported, backups can only be restored with the same version they were created with.

When you install TeamCity you usually have a data directory (probably ".BuildServer" in your case) and the software in a different location. You shouldn't delete the data directory, you should upgrade the database and data directory in place (TeamCity will prompt to do this when the new software starts, refer maintenance mode below).

If you continue with your proposed route you'll need to create a fresh TeamCity 10 database with the new schema version, however you'll loose all the other settings and data as that backup sounds like a project config only backup.

JetBrains provide detailed guides to perform upgrades:

- https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Upgrade
- https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/TeamCity+Maintenance+Mode

Comment: Can anyone guide me the steps  how to upgrade teamcity. because i am not getting the plot of the upgrade part.

Comment: @revzzz you'll have to provide more details about what part of JetBrains' install procedure you don't understand, they explain things pretty well in their guide.